# Make network changes permanent - C++

Tags: c++, linux, networking, network-interface

I need to allow an external client to change the IP of the Linux machine where the program is running (C++). I already know how to list all the local interfaces and the current IPs assigned to them. I also know how to programatically change said IPs.

What I need to know is how to make this change permanent so, if the machine reboots, it keeps the same network configuration.
What's the best way to do this? Manually parsing /etc/network/interfaces? Calling some linux command?

**Edit**: I'm using Debian.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, manipulating `/etc/network/interfaces` is the way to accomplish that (just store the backup in case things go wrong).

Also, if interfaces are managed by network manager (which is rarely the case for servers, but happens on the desktop), you may manipulate it via dbus calls, I think.

You should've mentioned distribution, btw, not the language — if you didn't mention the file it would be impossible to guess ;-)

Comment: Yep, sorry, I'm using Debian 6. So the way to go is manually parsing and editing /etc/network/interfaces? Damn... ;)

Comment: Sorry about that ;-) Actually, it's not a big deal, especially if no one else is poking around the file — you may even keep your data in more suitable for parsing file and generate `interfaces` from it. But well, you got the idea ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To make changes permanent, you have to write the network configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` and maybe DNS Servers (resolv.conf).

http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

If you don't want to parse the interfaces each time, you could save the IP and Network in a config file to restore it.
Then you have to rewrite "/etc/network/interfaces" only.

After Changes to the network interface configuration, you have to restart the network stack (distro specific).

Restart Interfaces with `auto` :

`$ /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Restart other interfaces:

`$ ifup [iface]`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ifconfig` and route `commands` in a script or better, you can edit the file you mention, depending on your Linux distro.